# Update flutter variable in the surface/overlay

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, qr-code

I have two flutter classes and would like to have the variable value in the flutter overlay/surface updated (qrscanner_frame) as soon as the value in the class qrscanner changes.

onPress is only used with a button, so I can't use it, because I get my text from the qrscanner class.

**qrscanner.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:qr_scanner/sides/qrscanner_frame.dart';
import 'package:qr_scanner/sides/qrscanner_frame.dart';

String QR = "";

class Scanner extends StatelessWidget {
  const Scanner({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String content_QR = "~";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('QR-Code-Scanner')),
      body: MobileScanner(
          allowDuplicates: false,
          controller: MobileScannerController(
              facing: CameraFacing.back, torchEnabled: true),
          onDetect: (barcode, args) {
            if (barcode.rawValue == null) {
              debugPrint('Failed to scan Barcode');
            } else {
              final String code = barcode.rawValue!;
              debugPrint('Barcode found! $code');
              content_QR = barcode.rawValue!;
              QR = content_QR;
              debugPrint("qrscanner" + " " + QR);
              Scanner_frame().scanner_var = "testi test";
              

            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

and
**qrscanner_frame**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:qr_scanner/mainview.dart';
import 'package:qr_scanner/sides/qrscanner.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:qrolo/qrolo.dart';

class Scanner_frame extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = "Text";
  String scanner_var = "~";



  @override
  _Scanner_frameState createState() => _Scanner_frameState();
}

class _Scanner_frameState extends State<Scanner_frame> {
  var _selectedIndex = 0;
  var value = "";



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      //appBar: AppBar(
      //title: Text(widget.title),
      //),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              /*
              Container(
              child: Text('${Scanner.content_QR}'),
                //child: Scanner(),
              ),
              Container(
                child: SizedBox(
                  //width: 200.0,
                  height: 1000.0,
                  child: Scanner(),
                ),
                //child: Scanner(),
              ),
               */
              Container(
                height: 1000.0,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(1, 1),
                      child: Scanner(),
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-0.07, 0.55),
                      child: Text(
                        '${value = Scanner_frame().scanner_var}',


                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      //Scanner()
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those purposes flutter have a state managing decisions, like "provider".
It might be a complicated to a novice in flutter, but i recomends you to read some documentation about it here: [Simple state managing app](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro)

For that case, you can also use callback, provided by Statefull parent widget, and it will look like this:

```
class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  String currentText = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextWidget(
            text: currentText,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25,
          ),
          GA23(
            callBack: (value) => setState(() {
              currentText = value;
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GA23 extends StatelessWidget {
  GA23({Key? key, required this.callBack}) : super(key: key);
  void Function(String value)
      callBack; // - you can modify an incoming param to any type
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Press me!"),
        onPressed: () => callBack("You just pressed!"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```